# Any equivalent for _satellite.isOutboundLink() that will work in Launch

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics, adobe-dtm

We have sites in DTM that make use of the _satellite.isOutboundLink() method but that seems to have seen eliminated in Launch.

Is there anything we can use to replace that method

Answer (score 0):

`_satellite.isOutboundLink()` is meant to be an internal function all this while. There is no official public facing documentation on this method.

You can make use of `s.linkInternalFilters`, which should be the list of domains not to be tracked.

If need be, this list can be dynamically updated with the Custom Code Editor of the Adobe Analytics' action type: Set Variables.

If you need `s.linkInternalFilters` outside of Adobe Analytics, one way is to create a custom function exposing `s.linkInternalFilters` to the global or `_satellite` namespace.